# How can I keep folders in sync between two Windows 7 PCs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-live-mesh

After much searching, I cannot find a similar question on SuperUser that is not massively outdated.

I currently use Windows Live Mesh to sync all of my folders in C:/Users/Nick (or the equivalent) between my desktop and laptop PCs. It really is a perfect solution, because I always have the latest version of all my files, no matter what machine I'm on.

However, Microsoft will be discontinuing Mesh soon and I need an alternative. Is there any satisfactory alternative to Mesh that will keep my computer's files Indentical to one another?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I keep folders synchronized between several machines over my home network?](http://superuser.com/questions/349/how-can-i-keep-folders-synchronized-between-several-machines-over-my-home-networ), also check out [Alternatives to Microsoft Live Mesh and Microsoft Live Sync?](http://superuser.com/questions/79744/alternatives-to-microsoft-live-mesh-and-microsoft-live-sync?rq=1)

Comment: If you find the answers to be outdated, please consider [adding a bounty](http://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties) to the existing question to request more/updated answers.

Comment: rsync is good  !

Answer (score 1):

I used to use Windows Live Mesh, especially the peer-to-peer syncing. When they announced that it would be discontinued, I searched for a replacement and found [Cubby](https://www.cubby.com/). From their [Features page](https://www.cubby.com/features/):

> Sync unlimited folders across computers without using your cloud storage. You can sync folders among your own computers so all your files are always at your fingertips.

As a bonus, you can also use [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/) (the makers of Cubby) to replace the remote control functionality of Windows Live Mesh.

Comment: Wonderful. I'll try this out when I get home. Everyone is suggested Cloud storage services, but that doesn't help me with several hundred GB of files.

Comment: Cubby charges for the peer-to-peer feature! Totally not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

How large is this folder?  Dropbox(2GB), sugarsync(5GB) and other can do this for you.  They are small to start of with but you can earn more space by inviting other users.  Worst case you can buy space if you really want too.

Comment: Cubby (5GB) is another alternative.

Comment: It's my entire documents folder. My Documents, Music, Pictures, etc. Several hundred GB.

Comment: justcloud offers an unlimited plan.

Comment: I imagine the bulk of your storage is music files.  You can load those into Google music, then they are accessible from any PC/mobile device on the net.  The rest should fit in a dropbx/sugarsync,gdrive....account.

Answer (score 0):

try google drive works same

[image: Google drive]

**To review:** Google Drive offers 5GB of free storage, almost the best prices beyond the free tier in a consumer product (Microsoft is better), and the biggest available online lockers. It's integrated into Google Docs so you can put your files from local apps alongside your Web files, which is pretty handy.
Google Drive is relatively easy to get started with on a PC, Mac, and Android device. It's a very strong product. We haven't even seen its iOS mobile app, nor the planned integration into Gmail and the Chrome OS operating system. These are coming.
Best for: People who live in the Googlesphere.

**Free storage:** 5GB; Price per 100GB: $60/year

Others:
**Dropbox**
Dropbox is the darling of the tech set for file synchronization and sharing, and for very good reasons: Setup is fast; The free service gives you a usable if limited 2GB of storage; and sharing files with other people is beautifully simple for both the sender and the receiver. If you're a Dropbox user and accustomed to the system, there's no need to move off of it. If you need a fast way to share a file with another user, or you want to park a file in the cloud to access it from anywhere or from other computers you own, it's still a fantastic experience -- better than Google Drive.
The upstart product from Google is not quite as simple or clear, but it does offer more free storage (5GB to Dropbox's 2GB) as well as better deals on paid storage.
Best for: Beautifully simple sharing.
**Free storage:** 2GB; Price per 100GB: $199/year

**Amazon Cloud Drive**

[image: Amazon Cloud drive]

Amazon has gotten into the Cloud Drive business with a new app. The Cloud Drive itself is not new, just the desktop software. You can store up to 5GB of files for free on Amazon's respected cloud servers. You can access your files from anywhere, of course. The big draw is that music files purchased from Amazon and stored on the drive don't count toward your storage allocation. As a promotion, in fact, any music files uploaded to the Amazon Cloud are stored for free. Amazon wants to push its Cloud Player online music app.
The downside: Amazon Cloud Drive is not a synchronizing hard drive like the other products in this list. When you're offline, you can't access or update files you've put on your drive. Rather, you copy files from your local system to the Drive. It's a good music storage product, but not nearly as useful for working with or sharing files as the other products in this comparison.
**Best for:** Storing a lot of music for free.
**Free storage:** 5GB; Price per 100GB: $100/year

**Much more details here:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use the free version of Syncback from 2BrightSparks to keep my Desktop PC synced with a laptop - http://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/freeware-hub.html- One free and two paid versions with differing functionality.  It's not quite Live Mesh but it I find the free version excellent for my needs.